CSP issues locally when working with vite/vue project
Working on a vite/vue based project, I m getting errors for CSP for client.js file, I debug and found that its failing on these lines
const cspNonce = "document" in globalThis ? document.querySelector("meta[property=csp-nonce]")?.nonce : void 0;
let lastInsertedStyle;
function updateStyle(id, content) {
  let style = sheetsMap.get(id);
  if (!style) {
    style = document.createElement("style");
    style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    style.setAttribute("data-vite-dev-id", id);
    style.textContent = content;
    if (cspNonce) {
      style.setAttribute("nonce", cspNonce);
    }
    if (!lastInsertedStyle) {
      document.head.appendChild(style); // <-- ERROR
      setTimeout(() => {
        lastInsertedStyle = void 0;
      }, 0);
    } else {
      lastInsertedStyle.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", style); // <-- ERROR
    }
    lastInsertedStyle = style;
  } else {
    style.textContent = content;
  }
  sheetsMap.set(id, style);
}

I added the nonce value to index.html page, and can verify that cspNonce is picking up correct value but even then its failing and throwing error
